# Can't Jump while moving left and right in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

A little bit of context, this is a 2D game I got it so I can move left right and jump, I can't jump while moving left and right and if I move while in midair then the player's decent dramatically slows down
Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float horSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float vertSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isJumping;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping)
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, horSpeed);
            isJumping = true;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-vertSpeed, 0);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(vertSpeed, 0);

        if (rb.velocity.y==0f)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    
}
```

I don't see what I've done wrong here, it might be that I'm registering the inputs on different lines of code but I'm not sure how to fix it if that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code presented is dealing with the velocity of an object. As such, you want to assign the calculated velocity as one value once all factors have been taken into account. I’ve corrected a few points and come up with this:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    // we store the initial velocity, which is a struct.
    var v = rb.velocity;

    if (v.y==0f)
        isJumping = false;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping) {
        v.y = vertSpeed;
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        v.x = -horSpeed;

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        v.x = horSpeed;

    rb.velocity = v;

}
```

The reason the code stores the velocity first, is because any changes you make to the temporary velocity struct needs to be applied back as a single value assignment to the rigid body’s velocity field (this is due to the difference between value and reference type objects). [Here’s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) the Microsoft discussion about the difference.

Comment: I think you inverted the usages of `vertSpeed` and `horSpeed` ;)

Comment: @derHugo you spelt “fixed” wrong ;)

Comment: what I mean is OP's expectations might be different from what is happening compared to OP's original code ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you can't jump while moving left or right is because you overwrite your "horizontal" speed when you move. Look at your code for moving left or right. Notice how you set your y velocity to 0 when a or d is pressed.

Try this:

```
private void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping) {
        rb.velocity.y = horSpeed;
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        rb.velocity.x = -vertSpeed;

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        rb.velocity.x = vertSpeed;

    if (rb.velocity.y==0f)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }

}
```

I think this should work but I don't have access to Unity right now so I'll have to wait til I get home to check it. Also, I didnt change it in this code but it seems like you have horSpeed and vertSpeed flipped. Up and down movement (a.k.a. jumping) should be vertSpeed.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: The reason that you can't jump while moving left or right is because you overwrite your "horizontal" speed when you move. Look at your code for moving left or right. Notice how you set your y velocity to 0 when a or d is pressed. Since you update these values after you detect a jump, your jump is overwritten. I'll edit my post in a minute with a  fix.

Comment: Ah, is it possible to not write a variable for the horizontal velocity?

Comment: Thank you, hopefully this should work but I also don’t have access to unity right now because I’ve turned off my pc to go to sleep